# Rails - controller coffee scripts stopped working after bootswatch theme

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I was asked to work on a task to change the entire sites theme. I did that successfully using bootswatch superhero theme. But the problem is there were controller jquery coffee scripts and they stopped working after applying the theme. It creates a theme folder inside 'app/assets/javascript//'
and all my controller coffee scripts reside out side of theme folder which is at the javascript root level ex: 'app/assets/javascripts/device.js.coffee'. If I move them inside the superhero folder they works. But there are ton of controller scripts and I dont want to move them all inside a theme folder. What I am missing here.???

```
config/initializer/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( superhero.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( superhero.js )
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery-ui
```

**My asset pipeline folder structure**
[image]

Comment: Define "work" and "stop working". What exactly are you observing?

Comment: For example, I have dynamic select menu and which is achieved through grouped_collection_select and little bit of jquery scripts. Its not working now, I see all the values (unfiltered) for the secondary dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for looking at it, I figured it out myself by thoroughly reading about how asset pipeline works. When you apply a new theme it creates "theme_name.js" under assets/javascripts/. BY default application.js is set to be precompile. But we will override this with the following in config/initializers/assets.rb. `"Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( superhero.js )"` so if you want your controller scripts to work which lives outside of the new theme, just include this directive `//= require_tree .` in theme_name.js file. Voila !! it worked ...